# nth-child being applied at all screen widths

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors

Currently I have the following for a react components css

```
export default styled.div

  @media (min-width: getEmFromPx(400)) {
  margin: ...
  width: ...

  :nth-child($2n+2) {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  }

  @media (min-width: getEmFromPx(700)) {
  margin: ...
  width: ...

  :nth-child($3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  }

  @media (min-width: getEmFromPx(1000)) {
  margin: ...
  width: ...

  :nth-child($3n+3) {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  }
```

I am setting which element in the div to apply the `margin-right 0px` while the other have a margin. This works perfectly on small screen sizes but for medium and large it seems the small nth selector is present and overriding the nth selectors in the medium and large... Is there a way to overcome this?

On chrome developer tools I can disabled the nth child selector for small screens which makes medium screens work perfectly. It was my understand that at different media screens the selector would be updated?

Comment: The code you have written doesnt seem to be valid css. Can you please update it with as much details as possible?

Comment: Sorry updated it so it can hopefuly be understood better. If it's any help it's for a react component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first media query `@media (min-width: getEmFromPx(400))` will be apply to all screens having 400px or greater than 400px, because you are using min-width (it is it should applicable min this and up all).

in your 2nd and 3rd media query you are doing same thing, so no need to write it twice.
Here you are setting `margin-right: 0` to `nth-child(3n+3)`, but you will have to reset `nth-child(2n+2)` element which is defined in previous media query. Because `nth-child(2n+2)` will be applicable all screens 400px above.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by resetting? Do you mean in second and third media query have another n-th child selector? Or do you mean only have one n-th child selector and have some logic to determine current screen size?

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/6xdz928h/1/

in second and third media media use another nth-child(2n+2) { margin-right: unset }

because you are setting margin-right value 0 to nth-child(3n+3) and still value for (2n+2) is 0.